# How to Auto Generate Code for Stored Procedure Column Data Types - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, temp-tables

My desired end result is to simply be able to SELECT from a Stored Procedure.  I've searched the Internet and unfortunately the Internet said this can't be done and that you **first need to create a Temp Table** to store the data.  My problem is that you must first define the columns in the Temp Table before Executing the STORED Procedure.  This is just time consuming.  I simply want to take the data from the stored procedure and just stick it into a Temp Table.

What is the **FASTEST** route to achieve this from a coding perspective?  To put it simply it's time consuming to first have to lookup the returned fields from a Stored Procedure and then write them all out.

> Is there some sort of tool that can just build the CREATE Table Statement based on the Stored Procedure?  See screenshot for clarification.

[image]

Most of the Stored Procedures I'm dealing with have 50+ fields.  I don't look forward to defining each of these fields manually.

Here is good [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/insert-results-of-a-stored-procedure-into-a-temporary-table) that got me this far but not what I was hoping.  This still takes too much time.  What are experienced SQL Server guys doing?  I've only just recently made the jump from Oracle to SQL Server and I see that Temp Tables are a big deal in SQL Server from what I can tell.

Comment: Something doesn't quite add up here. You are asking to do a select from a stored procedure. If your stored procedure has a select in it, it will return a data set. So unless you're *doing something* with that temp table, this seems to be really convoluted for nothing. There are tools which will expand out a column list from a table. Maybe some that might do so for a stored procedure. But why?

Comment: @JacobH The why... Testing - I can't join on a Stored Procedure to other tables.

Comment: @CodeNovice After seeing your last comment, you may want to consider Table-Valued Functions.   If the stored procedures in question do not perform any updates or require dynamic SQL, this may be yet another alternative.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Oh yes thank you.  I have knowledge of Table Valued Functions as they are the closest thing to Oracle's Pipelined functions that returns Tables/Rows.  The database I work out of I do not have that level of access to create table valued functions.  In Oracle I had my own schema where I could test without restriction.  Frustrating I don't have my own 'space' within SQL Server.  If there is a way to provide a single user with their own 'space' within SQL Server I am not aware of it.

Comment: @CodeNovice See if your DBA can create your own schema.  So rather than [dbo].[...], it would be [YourUserID].[...] or even create a sandbox database (on the same server) where you can create functionality which can be called/executed from the primary database.  For example select * from [MySandbox].[dbo],[myTableValuedFunction]()

Comment: @CodeNovice Once your improved functionality can be demonstrated and validated, it can migrated it to the primary database.   My advice is keep pushing for the Value-Added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind `##temp table` and some dynamic SQL

**NOTE:** As Luis Cazares correctly pointed out... the ##temp runs the risk of collision due to concurrency concerns

**Example**

```
Declare @SQL  varchar(max) = 'Exec [dbo].[prc-App-Lottery-Search] ''8117'''
Declare @temp varchar(500) = '##myTempTable'

Set @SQL = '
If Object_ID(''tempdb..'+@temp+''') Is Not NULL Drop Table '+@temp+';   
Create Table '+@temp+' ('+stuff((Select concat(',',quotename(Name),' ',system_type_name) 
                                  From  sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(@SQL,null,null )  A 
                                  Order By column_ordinal
                                  For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') +') 

Insert '+@temp+' '+@SQL+'
'
Exec(@SQL)

Select * from ##myTempTable
```

Comment: That's nice. One just have to hope that there's no concurrency happening. Some warning in the answer would be useful.

Comment: You are 100% correct in raising the concern.  I'm simply not clear on the actual USE CASE ... My initial thought was discovery / meta data

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Yes it's discovery.  I'm learning the capabilities of SQL Server and so any new knowledge/tips are appreciated.

Comment: @CodeNovice Learning is the fun part.  I learn something new every day here on SO

Answer (score 3):

You have several options to ease your task. However, these won't be fully automatic. Be aware that these won't work if there's dynamic sql in the procedure's code. You might be able to format the result from the functions to increase the automation allowing you to copy and paste easily.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object(OBJECT_ID('report.MyStoredProcedureWithAnyColumns'), 0) ;  

SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(N'EXEC report.MyStoredProcedureWithAnyColumns', null, 0) ;  

EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set @tsql = N'EXEC report.MyStoredProcedureWithAnyColumns';
GO
```

Comment: I'm glad you put this here, I can make this work automatically for me.